# Paintbrush painting in places not intended

Tags: texture-painting

In painting this model I have found several instances where I get strange effects.  Either the area will not be covered at all, or I will paint on one area, only to find another area is also getting covered unintentionally.

To best illustrate this, I have taken a snip of a number I tried to paint with the brush mask. Is this related to seams?

[image]

Comment: it means your unwrap is not good, probably UV faces overlapping, if your goal is to directly paint in the 3D view, the easiest way is to use the Smart UV Project unwrap mode, this way you're sure there will be no overlapping

Comment: Thank you.  That clarifies it.